# Как я могу менять содержание <div> при клике, помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$("document").ready( function () {
   $("#button").click(function(event){
  $("#map").HTML(template);
});
```

});

Что здесь не так? Я хочу чтобы при клике на кнопку #button менялся содержимое #map. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Так и делать. Только вместо `HTML` надо `html`

```js
let template = `<p>new value</p>`;


$("#button").click(function(event){
  $("#map").html(template);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=map>start</div>
<button id=button>click</button>
```